# Angular - find in page content, highlight and jump to location in page (like in vscode)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angularjs-directive

Need to highlight the word that is been searched and jump to the word location(Next-Previous), without add < mark > tags
like that exist here

https://github1s.com/akveo/nebular/blob/HEAD/src/app/components-list/components-list.component.ts   (ctrl+F)

[find in page content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAych.png)

Comment: What do you mean by saying add tags?

Comment: @AtharvaSharma without add < mark > tag arround the word